# Whats the word you use when damages happen to someone and they get something for it? Like I break someone's leg and I have to pay them money for it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm really annoyed because this is a word I cannot think of. I was talking to someone and they got money stolen and I said to them ''I hope you get the money back for...'' and I can't think of the word. It's similar to repercussions but it's when someone gets a 'reward' when something bad happens. Like they're entitled to... if you crash into their car. Please help lol

Edit - thank you so much to the person who commented, the word I was looking for was compensation.

Comment: *Reparations* are also similar to compensation.

Comment: By the way, you've edited to say that KillingTime provided the answer you were looking for. It would be a nice next step to accept that answer.

Comment: Punitive damages

Comment: [Recompense](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+recompense&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+recompense&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l2j0i22i30l7.8529j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 11):

**Compensation** (Noun)

1. Something, typically money, awarded to someone in recognition of loss, suffering, or injury.
   ‘*he is seeking compensation for injuries suffered at work*’

[Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/definition/compensation)

Answer (score 5):

Another word that suits is **restitution**, it might even be a better fit than "compensation", since you talk about a "reward". [The Wikipedia article on restitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restitution) quotes the definition from American Jurispudence:

*[restitution is defined as] not only the restoration or giving back of something to its rightful owner and returning to the status quo but also compensation, reimbursement, indemnification, or reparation for benefits derived from, or for loss or injury caused to, another. In summary, therefore, the word "restitution" means the relinquishment of a benefit or the return of money or other property obtained through an improper means to the person from whom the property was taken*

Answer (score 3):

I hope you get **made whole**.

https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/make_whole

It’s a term found in legal writing.  It has the advantage of being general. Compensation for damages might only be part of making someone whole.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be **reparation**.

*the action of making amends for a wrong one has done, by providing
payment or other assistance to those who have been wronged.*

Source: Google's English dictionary provided by Oxford Languages.

Comment: You should include the source of your definition.

Comment: @KillingTime, you're right. You can look it up in the english version of Google by typing: "define: reparations". Google gets their dictionary from Oxford Languages, as they mention in the result.

Comment: While this is true, for political reasons this word would probably not be used in the US in the given circumstance.